# Error condition using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hello i'm trying to a correct condition in rails

This conditions is working

```
   def get_last_insurance
     insurance = Insurance.find(:all, :conditions=>{:policy_id=>self.id}, :order=>"id desc")
     return insurance.first
  end
```

I want insurance.all.

i tried this but i'm getting errors

```
  def get_last_insurance
     insurance = Insurance.find(:all, :conditions=>{:policy_id=>self.id}, :generate_letter => 1}))
     return insurance.all
  end
```

Comment: since you are doing insurance.fnid(:all) you dont need to explicitly return insurance.all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to return all your insurance. You are trying call `.all` on an array of insurance's  which is why you are getting the error

```
  def get_last_insurance
      Insurance.find(:all, :conditions=>{:policy_id=>self.id, :generate_letter => 1}))
  end
```